# What kind of convergence is $\sum |f_n|$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

We know that $\sum |f_n|$ converges on $E\subseteq \mathbb R$ then $\sum f_n$ is said to converge absolutely on $E$.

But in terms of pointwise or uniform convergence, I am willing to know what kind of convergence is the above. meaning by, if we say $\sum f_n$ is absolutely convergent, are we saying $\sum |f_n|$ is pointwise convergence or uniform convergence ?

Please clear my doubt. thanks in advance

Comment: This means pointwise unless context determine otherwise. NB there are theorems that state that pointwise convergence implies absolute convergence under certain conditions on $(f_n)$ and $E$ (e.g., if the $f_n$ are continuous and $E$ is compact).

Comment: This means the point wise convergence. There is a theorem says that " In any Banach space if $ \sum ||x_n|| $ is convergent as a real number, then $ \sum x_n $ is convergent within the space. You can use this theorem to prove your statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute convergence is pointwise convergence, because there is a statement which you mentioned, i.e. $\sum|f_n|$ -converges, then $\sum f_n$ - converges, and under convergence of $\sum f_n$ we mean poinwise covergence,if it was not mentioned previously about anything else. But it can also mean uniform convergence in special conditions (example is uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}c_n z^n$ on every compact subset of convergence circle )

Comment: And in case, when we say the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum a_nx^n$ is $r$, are we saying $\sum a_nx^n$ converges pointwise on $(-r, r)$ ?